# WSDL: Error to Add Service Reference C# on VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, web-services, wsdl, service-reference

I get this error when i try to include the reference of the WSDL service: [Link](http://www.comercioweb.com.br/ws/servidor.wsdl)

> The document at the url http://www.comercioweb.com.br/ws/servidor.wsdl
>   was not recognized as a known document type. The error message from
>   each known type may help you fix the problem:
>   - Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The root element of a W3C XML Schema should be  and its namespace should be
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.
>   - Report from 'DISCO Document' is 'Discovery document at the URL http://www.comercioweb.com.br/ws/servidor.wsdl could not be found.'.
>     - The document format is not recognized.
>   - Report from 'WSDL Document' is 'There is an error in XML document (8, 33).'.
>     - Namespace prefix 's' is not defined. Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved:
>   'http://www.comercioweb.com.br/ws/servidor.wsdl'. The remote server
>   returned an unexpected response: (417) Expectation failed. The remote
>   server returned an error: (417) Expectation failed. If the service is
>   defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding
>   the service reference again.

Somebody know why this error? 
Delphi 7 import it very well...and [www.wsdl-analyzer.com](http://www.wsdl-analyzer.com) say zero errors on wsdl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WSDL(xml) was generated incorrect...
For some reason the Delphi dont detect it.. but on runtime it gives me a error... on c#/visual studio the error came when i create the service reference.